# I want hide view more button if price is blank

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to hide view more button only for those product which product  have no price .this is working for out of stock product .but I want remove read more button only for product with no price .

```
 if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
        function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
            global $product;
            if ( ! $product->$product->price() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
            woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
        }
    }
```

I want use somthing like this

```
if( empty($product->price) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of eliminating the loop/add-to-cart.php template all together, why not hook into the price html Woocommerce hooks?

```
/*
 * Remove price HTML if stock is null
 *
 * Sources:
 * http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_stock_quantity/
 */
add_filter( "woocommerce_get_price_html", "wphelpsanjay_remove_price_if_no_stock", 10, 2 );
add_filter( "woocommerce_variable_price_html", "wphelpsanjay_remove_price_if_no_stock", 10, 2 );

function wphelpsanjay_remove_price_if_no_stock( $price, $product ) {
    if ( null === $product->get_stock_quantity()) {
        return "";
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Tom@ i do not want remove price I want remove view more button if  product price is empty

Comment: Tom Morton@you  there ,I need your help bro